# Why is this stopping after defining the MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the server is stopping immediately after $array_transactions is defined.  I tried to echo text before that line and it will show, but if I put the text after that line, then it will not.  Why is the while loop not continuing?

```
<?php

$date1 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM transactions 
                      WHERE userid='$userid' 
                      ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1",$con) 
           or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($date1))
{
    $date = date_create($row['date']);
}

function priceformat($price){
    $newprice = round($price,2);
    return $newprice;
}

$array = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM transactions 
                      WHERE userid='$userid' 
                      ORDER BY date ASC",$con) 
           or die(mysql_error());

$currentdate = date("o-m-d");

while( (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($currentdate)) && 
       ($result = mysql_fetch_array($array)))
{
    // Check if $date exists in transactions table
    $array_transactions = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                       FROM transactions 
                                       WHERE (userid='$userid') 
                                         AND (date='$date')",$con) 
        or die(mysql_error());

    // If entries for $date exist, sum transactions
    if(mysql_num_rows($array_transactions) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($array_transactions)) {
            if($row['type'] == 'D') {
                $balance_affect = $row['amount'] + $balance_affect;
            } else {
                $balance_affect = (0 - $row['amount']) + $balance_affect;
            }
        }
    }


    // Check if $date exists in trades table
    // If entries for $date exist, sum trades

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="v-align-middle text-center">';
            echo $result['date'];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td class="v-align-middle text-center">';
            $currentbalance = $previousbalance + $balance_affect;
            echo '$' . $currentbalance . '';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td class="v-align-middle text-center">';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td class="v-align-middle text-center">';
            echo '$0';
        echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $previousbalance = $currentbalance;

    $date = date("o-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));                                        
}

?>
```

Comment: Is `mysql_error` returning anything?

Comment: not sure about connections in php/mysql but is it because 2 result queries `$array` and `$array_transactions` are both open on the same connection `$con` at the same time?

Comment: No errors are being reported @Mureinik and I also tried removing the brackets, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you allowed to have simultaneous queries on the same connection, @Rhumborl?

Comment: @user3765935 As I say, I don't know, but the code looks ok, so it might be something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$date1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE userid=".$userid." ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1",$con) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($date1)){
    $date = date_create($row['date']);
}                                                                                       

function priceformat($price){
    $newprice = round($price,2);
    return $newprice;
}

$array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE userid=".$userid." ORDER BY date ASC",$con) or die(mysql_error());
$currentdate = date("o-m-d");

while((strtotime($date) <= strtotime($currentdate)) && ($result = mysql_fetch_array($array))) {
    // Check if $date exists in transactions table
    $array_transactions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE userid=".$userid." AND date='".$date."' ",$con) or die(mysql_error());

    // If entries for $date exist, sum transactions
    if(mysql_num_rows($array_transactions) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($array_transactions)) {
            if($row['type'] == 'D') {
                $balance_affect = $row['amount'] + $balance_affect;
            }else{
                $balance_affect = (0 - $row['amount']) + $balance_affect;
            }
        }
    }


    // Check if $date exists in trades table
        // If entries for $date exist, sum trades

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="v-align-middle text-center">';
            echo $result['date'];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td class="v-align-middle text-center">';
            $currentbalance = $previousbalance + $balance_affect;
            echo '$' . $currentbalance . '';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td class="v-align-middle text-center">';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td class="v-align-middle text-center">';
            echo '$0';
        echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $previousbalance = $currentbalance;

    $date = date("o-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));                                        
    }

?>
```

Comment: There is a lot of code there. Can you explain your changes (if any)?

Comment: php variable concatenation problem try simple `".$userid."` insted of  `$userid` in sql